# Associate Document with all Candidates in Candidate_Document table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [CandidateDocsAssociation](
[Row_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Doc_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Candidate_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have the above table structure to store the association between documents and candidates. Row_ID is an auto generated primary key. Doc_ID is a foreign key referencing the documents table. Candidate_ID is also a foreign key referencing the Candidates table.

A candidate can be associated with more than one document and one document can be associated with multiple candidates.

What i want to achieve is insert a default common document (Doc_ID) for all candidates(DISTINCT) if a Candidate_ID row with a DOC_ID of 2 does not already exist.

I'm not getting the below code to work

```
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Candidate_ID from CandidateDocsAssociation
      WHERE Doc_ID <> (SELECT   Doc_ID FROM Doc_Table WHERE Doc_Name = N'Default'))
      BEGIN
      INSERT CandidateDocsAssociation (Doc_ID, Candidate_ID) VALUES  ((SELECT Doc_ID FROM Doc_Table WHERE Doc_Name = N'Default'),Candidate_ID)
      END
      GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about while-loop, SQL is about set manipulation so you must adjust your thinking to it. What you need is set of candidates that do not have document with id=2 associated. For each such candidate you need to create an association with the default document. Let's try to write that down:

```
INSERT INTO [CandidateDocsAssociation] VALUES([Candidate_ID], [Doc_ID])
SELECT [Candidate_ID], 2
FROM [Candidate] c  -- I assume you have table of all candidates
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM [CandidateDocsAssociation] a
  WHERE a.[Candidate_ID] = c.[Candidate_ID] AND a.[Doc_ID] = 2
)
```